# web3.js to receive payment from auction or sell

Tags: solidity

I would like to receive payments on my contract and be able to withdraw it to my address from my website.

I know how to do basic apps like create a token or transferring a token to an address in the browser,

However I do not know how to create the interaction for the web3.js to launch metamask with the right amount and the right address when clicking the "purchase" button.

I know there is a Open Zeppelin PullPayment.sol, but I do not know how to connect it